# Is there any normative theory within pragmatic ethics?

Tags: ethics, pragmatism

I've read wikipedia's article on [pragmatic ethics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatic_ethics) and it does not produce any norms. Rather, it is only a template for normative ethical theories, like how deontology is a template and CI is a real normative theory. This makes me wonder if anyone has developed a normative theory that belongs to pragmatic ethics? Maybe, based on game theories, accepting humaninty is divided in groups of different interests, etc. If there are such theories (which do not completely belong to any other groups like deontology, virtue ethics, etc.), what are the most notable of them?

Comment: Here is a recent survey by Serra [What Is and What Should Pragmatic Ethics Be?](http://lnx.journalofpragmatism.eu/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/SERRA.pdf), Laudan's ["normative naturalism"](http://www.philosophy.uncc.edu/mleldrid/SAAP/USC/TP25.html) is arguably a version. But pragmatism generally rejects the normative/descriptive distinction, at least in its traditional forms.

Comment: @Conifold, my ethics are rejecting metaethical distinction as well: I think people can achieve universal agreement and will do it. So, it was somehow predictable there is no distinction between normative and descriptive in pragmatic ethics. Normatively it only boils down to methods.

Comment: I forgot to mention, irreducible normativity plays central role in Brandom's pragmatism of course, but he is interested in its role in semantics, not ethics. Still, Wolfendale has an interesting blog post on his position's [ethical implications](https://deontologistics.wordpress.com/2010/02/27/brandom-and-ethics/).